# OCFS2 updating procedures

Tags: redhat, yum, rhel5, ocfs2

We plan to use OCFS2 in a project running Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 5.6 because we found OCFS2 to be much simpler to set up than GFS.

I am, however, worried about the upgrade process since I understand OCFS2 depends on the kernel version number. If I perform `yum update` on my RHEL host I might receive a newer kernel version. What would be the correct way to keep OCFS2 updated and working?

What is the best practice to have an OCFS2 system that runs a long time and also gets kernel updates?

Comment: I just saw that the guys are Oracle have only made OCFS2 available for their own kernel. I cannot see the source to it or patches for the vanilla kernel anywhere on their website. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, you can grab OCFS2 off their project website. Just make sure you get the right kernel version then you can use it with RHEL/CentOS, etc. 
http://oss.oracle.com/projects/ocfs2/

Comment: Yeah, I should have said "the 1.6 version of OCFS2". The older version (1.2 and 1.4) are available as source downloads and (as I see it) have been merged upstread. If anyone can point to a source download of the 1.6 version of ocfs2, that would be grand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have `exclude = kernel*` in our yum.conf file to avoid this exact problem. I should add that we only kernel update when there is a urgent need to do so and when oracle blesses the kernel

Answer (score -1):

> If I perform yum update on my RHEL host I might receive a newer kernel version

Are you sure?  AFAIK, the whole point of RHEL is not to change *anything* on the same system release.  You just get bugfixes, not upgrades.

Comment: Unfortunately I am sure. Also RHEL bounces you from 5.5 to 5.6 without you really noticing. I have had several kernel updates during the last few months. You can imagine my surprise when I found out.